# How to use startmsg.regex in Rsyslog

Tags: rsyslog

The following is my conf file. I want to add config for `startmsg.regex`.

I added the following line in my config file

```
  startmsg.regex="^[[:digit:]]{4}\/[[:digit:]]{2}\/[[:digit:]]{2} [[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}"
```

```
ModLoad imfile
$InputFilePollInterval 10
$PrivDropToGroup proxy
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog


$InputFileName /var/log/app/cache.log
$InputFileTag app-error:
$InputFileStateFile stat-app-error
$InputFileSeverity error
$InputFilePersistStateInterval 20000
$InputRunFileMonitor

  startmsg.regex="^[[:digit:]]{4}\/[[:digit:]]{2}\/[[:digit:]]{2} [[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}"





$template AppError,"error %msg%\n"

if $programname == 'app-error' then @@0.0.0.0:12345;AppError
if $programname == 'app-error' then ~
```

And when I check my config file using `rsyslogd -N1`, I am getting error.
What is the correct way to use this feature ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is my conf file which I am using to send my logs via rsyslog.
I am also adding sample logs.

This configuration will match that each event starts with YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS
and then send to my TCP endpoint.
This configuration can be used with multi line logs

```
module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10") #needs to be done just once
# File 1
input(type="imfile"
  File="/var/log/app/my.log"
  Tag="app-error"
  Severity="error"
  startmsg.regex="^[[:digit:]]{4}/[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2} [[:digit:]]{1,2}:[[:digit:]]{1,2}:[[:digit:]]{1,2}"
)


$PrivDropToGroup proxy
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog


$template AppError,"error %msg%\n"

if $programname == 'app-error' then @@0.0.0.0:12345;AppError
if $programname == 'app-error' then ~
```

Sample Log :

```
2017/10/24 09:14:06 id1|   Took 0.00 seconds (  0.00 entries/sec).
CPU Usage: 0.052 seconds = 0.032 user + 0.020 sys
Maximum Resident Size: 104944 KB
Page faults with physical i/o: 0
2017/10/24 09:14:06 id1| found error
```

Now rsyslog will send my multi line logs as a single event to my tcp end point as follows :

```
2017/10/24 09:14:06 id1|   Took 0.00 seconds (  0.00 entries/sec). \nCPU Usage: 0.052 seconds = 0.032 user + 0.020 sys \nMaximum Resident Size: 104944 KB \nPage faults with physical i/o: 0
2017/10/24 09:14:06 id1| found error
```

Comment: I can proof it, this solution is working. Several thoughts: templating isn't working for me (rsyslogd -v == 8.16.0), just have removed `AppError` and can see logs on server side.